# Как из xsd файла создать таблицу

Tags: xsd

Есть набор xsd файлов обьемом 41Кб. Внутри этих файлов могут быть и xml данные, но может и не быть xml данных внутри файлов. Требуется из  xsd -файлов создать таблицы и где есть xml данные - залить их в таблицы. Буду очень благодарен за ответ.

Comment: А что за таблицы?

Answer (score 0):

Есть программы, которые это делают, [вот тут обсуждалось](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237938/how-to-convert-xsd-to-human-readable-documentation).

- Одна из прог, которую советовали в том вопросе (имеет триал версию) http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_editor/xml_schema_documentation.html